# ARCore Cloud Anchors - Anchor Hosting is not configured

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm making my own app based on the SDK demo app, but when I try to resolve an anchor from his ID it gives me this error:

```
2020-12-15 12:45:27.019 12668-12668/demo E/native: status.cc:161 FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:3601
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/persistence/cloud_anchor_manager.cc:383
Anchor Hosting is not configured. [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_CLOUD_ANCHORS_NOT_CONFIGURED']
```

Here the complete log: https://pastebin.com/hEvhRxtq

I set the session overriding the getSessionConfig method in ARFragment, like in [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/google-cloud-anchors-with-sceneform-in-android-7b8e6e0f3128).
If I print session.getConfig().getCloudAnchorMode() before the resolveCloudAnchor call the result is ENABLED.
What could the problem be?

- Android Studio: 4.0
- ARCore SDK for Android: 1.20.0
- Device manufacturer, model, and O/S: Samsung S7, Android 8.0.0
- Google Play Services for AR (ARCore): 1.22.203220523